# Javascript is acting buggy on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

It's a little hard to describe as I have very little knowledge about Javascript, but it seems to be causing some issues with my Chrome browser.  The best way I can say it is that a lot of things that use Javascript are broken.  For example, when I visit a Wikipedia page and try to click 'show' on a nav-box, it takes me to the top of the page instead of opening the box.  These things still work on IE, so I know this issue at least limited to Chrome.  I don't know how this issue started.  What exactly is going on here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: uninstall and re-install a fresh copy.

Comment: Chrome or Javascript?

Comment: Probably you have supressed pop-up windows.

Comment: What can I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

It's been resolved.  I did a full reinstallation of Chrome.